# Why do I get a 'inout simd_float3' (aka 'inout float3') is not convertible to 'float3' error while converting to data from SceneKit node in Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opentok

I am using SceneKit and ARKit. The following function is getting called in a delegate method:

```
func prepare(videoFrame: OTVideoFrame) {
    let cameraNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes.first {
        $0.camera != nil
    }
    if let node = cameraNode, let cam = node.camera {
        let data = Data(fromArray: [
            node.simdPosition.x,  
            node.simdPosition.y,
            node.simdPosition.z,
            node.eulerAngles.x,
            node.eulerAngles.y,
            node.eulerAngles.z,
            Float(cam.zNear),
            Float(cam.fieldOfView)
            ])

        var err: OTError?
        videoFrame.setMetadata(data, error: &err)
        if let e = err {
            print("Error adding frame metadata: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error at the `node.simdPosition.x` line:

```
'inout simd_float3' (aka 'inout float3') is not convertible to 'float3'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How is `Data.init(fromArray:)` defined?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targeting? Looking at the iOS 12 documentation simdPosition is a `simd_float3` or `float3` struct which has a x property.